# Drop shadows on sides of webpage to achieve paper effect?

Tags: css, html, themes, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to create my website, and I want the sides to a different color and have drop shadow, making a floating paper effect. [Here](http://maineintegrative.com/) is an example of what I'm looking to achieve. How would I go about doing this, while using Bootstrap?

Comment: It's not too difficult. Look up css box-shadow. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
/* the numbers move the shadow: 1) r-l; 2) up-down; 3) blur. Then the color. */
box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #ccc;
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you much.